# Could you suggest a good media streaming server for mobile phone clients?

Tags: mobile, media

I am looking for an open source media streaming server.

It should have an API. I want to be able to stream videos to a mobile phones. Could you tell me the relative advantages and disadvantages of the software. Currently I am experimenting with [red5](http://osflash.org/red5)

Comment: Could you clarify "stream"? Would HTTP streaming be enough or do you need a protocol supporting seek like RTMP?

Comment: anything would do as long as it is not buggy. if i design a server from scratch then it would be buggy and i would have to take care to adhere to standards. if i have some server to start off with then i can improve on its code base. i want something for windows or linux. red5 supports only flash video streaming, which means that i need flash lite on my mobile, which i want to avoid. on the mobile client i would be working with Java ME.
Thanks

Comment: something with http would be great.

Comment: what mobile platform would you be targeting? It seems that the *client* would be more important.. unless you're looking to stream *from* the phone

Comment: right now i am not thinking of streaming from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Using Darwin Streaming Server and VLC you should be able to get a quite powerful streaming solution. Probably not the easiest solution to setup but you should be able to achieve almost everything you need.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit your clients to using ASX, I know that Microsoft has a Media streaming server, I have no idea how reliable it is. I know it exists.